# "gulp package-solution" will raise this warning "- [package-solution] This is not a production build (--ship or --production).."

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, typescript, applicationcustomizers

I am following the steps inside this link @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint to deploy my SPFX extension of type application customizers to our app catalog. but when i run this command `gulp package-solution` i got this warning :-

```
[22:04:21] Warning - [package-solution] This is not a production build (--ship or --production), therefore the "includeClientSideAssets" setting will be ignored.
```

and when i deploy the application to our app catalog i got that the app will request its content from local host as follow:-

[image]

and when i added the app to our site collection i will get an error inside the browser console that a file from local host can not be loaded, as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1):

your config is set to use Debug,
simple run 'gulp bundle --ship', so you can perform  'gulp package-solution --ship'